# Flask: how to authenticate user on subdomain?

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

A user logins in through mydomain.com. How can I make it so that when they visit their own server at subdomain.mydomain.com, that they won't have to relogin? Alternatively, if a user logs in through subdomain.mydomain.com, they should find themselves logged in at mydomain.com

subdomain.mydomain.com points to another server with a different ip.

Comment: Do the two systems support the same cookies?

Comment: I used flask-login once in a site that I made. I think it has a feature to remember cookies in subdomain. Refer Here : https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/